# To prove $\sum{a_n}$ converges if and only if $\sum 2^n a_{2^n}$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series

Prove $$\sum{a_n}$$ converges if and only if $$\sum 2^n a_{2^n}$$ converges.

This is assuming that $a_n$ is decreasing.

Comment: Hi, and welcome! I've edited your post to hopefully fix the subscript error you mentioned; please check that it's correct. Can you also share your thoughts on the problem? As it's stated, it's false - just choose any non-convergent sequence that has zeros for the terms corresponding to index $2^n$.

Comment: Are you assuming that the terms are decreasing?

Comment: What you're looking for is almost certainly the _Cauchy Condensation Test_ (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test )

Answer (score 3):

Consider the sequence

$$a_n = \left\{ \begin{array}{lr} 0 :& n = 2^k \text{ for some } k \\ 1 :& \text{ else } \end{array}\right.$$

---

As Steven Stadnicki commented, you're probably after the [Cauchy condensation test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test), a proof of which is in the linked article. Note that $a_n$ fails this test because it's not non-increasing.