# Convergence of a series $\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(\log\log n)^{\log n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I wanted to test the convergence of the series $$\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(\log\log n)^{\log n}}.$$ First I, apply the Cauchy condensation test i.e., $\displaystyle\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{2^n}{(\log\log 2^n)^{\log2^n}}$ which is same as $\displaystyle\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{2^n}{[\log(n\log2)]^{n\log 2}}$.

Next apply, root test i.e.,
$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}\left[\frac{2^n}{[\log(n\log2)]^{n\log 2}}\right]^{1/n}$ which becomes $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{2}{[\log(n\log2)]^{\log 2}}=0<1$, by root test the series  $\displaystyle\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{2^n}{[\log(n\log2)]^{n\log 2}}$, converges, hence Cauchy Condensation test  the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(\log\log n)^{\log n}}$ converges.

Is this correct? or any other simple technique available?

Comment: This seems correct yes, though you'd need to show the decreasingness of the general term (there are [counterexamples](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/556270/1104384) to the test when this is not satisfied). Another approach is seeing that $1/(\log\log n)^{\log n} = 1/n^{\log\log\log n}$, and observe that for $n \geq n_0$ for some "big enough" $n_0$, $\log\log\log n \geq 2$ for example, meaning that for those $n$ you can compare the series with the one of $1/n^2$ which converges.

Comment: @BrunoB, I think that $\,n_0=10^{703}$ is big enough as long as the function $\,\log\,$ is the natural logarithm.

Comment: $n_0=4000000$ is more apprehensible and we still get $\frac 1{n^\alpha}$ with $\alpha>1$ (just slightly).